# React + Material UI Table pagination not showing correctly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-dom

## Material UI Table not showing correctly when changing page

By receiving an array of Artist Objects through props I want to have a checklist table. Everything seems to work, however when changing page/sorting, more than "rowsPerPage" rows are shown. Also this effect duplicates when switching back and forth.

An artist Object: {id: number, name: string, email: string, checked: boolean}

example of props.values.artists: [{id: 1, name: "Tester", email: "mail", checked: false}, {id: 1, name: "bob", email: "test@live.com", checked: false}]

sorry that the code isn't very runnable!

here is the example I used from material: https://material-ui.com/components/tables/

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import clsx from "clsx";
import {
  createStyles,
  lighten,
  makeStyles,
  Theme
} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@material-ui/core/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TablePagination from "@material-ui/core/TablePagination";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import TableSortLabel from "@material-ui/core/TableSortLabel";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";

/*function createData(id: number, name: string, email: string, checked: boolean) {
  return { id, name, email, checked };
}*/

function desc(a: any, b: any, orderBy: any) {
  if (b[orderBy] < a[orderBy]) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (b[orderBy] > a[orderBy]) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

function stableSort<T>(array: Object[], cmp: (a: T, b: T) => number) {
  const stabilizedThis = array.map((el, index) => [el, index] as [T, number]);
  stabilizedThis.sort((a, b) => {
    const order = cmp(a[0], b[0]);
    if (order !== 0) return order;
    return a[1] - b[1];
  });
  return stabilizedThis.map(el => el[0]);
}

type Order = "asc" | "desc";

function getSorting<K extends keyof any>(
  order: Order,
  orderBy: K
): (a: { [key in K]: any }, b: { [key in K]: any }) => number {
  return order === "desc"
    ? (a, b) => desc(a, b, orderBy)
    : (a, b) => -desc(a, b, orderBy);
}

interface HeadCell {
  disablePadding: boolean;
  id: any;
  label: string;
  numeric: boolean;
}

const headCells: HeadCell[] = [
  {
    id: "name",
    numeric: false,
    disablePadding: true,
    label: "Artists"
  },
  {
    id: "email",
    numeric: true,
    disablePadding: false,
    label: "Email"
  }
];

interface EnhancedTableProps {
  classes: ReturnType<typeof useStyles>;
  numSelected: number;
  onRequestSort: (event: React.MouseEvent<unknown>, property: any) => void;
  onSelectAllClick: (
    event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
    checked: boolean
  ) => void;
  order: Order;
  orderBy: string;
  rowCount: number;
}

function EnhancedTableHead(props: EnhancedTableProps) {
  const {
    classes,
    onSelectAllClick,
    order,
    orderBy,
    numSelected,
    rowCount,
    onRequestSort
  } = props;
  const createSortHandler = (property: any) => (
    event: React.MouseEvent<unknown>
  ) => {
    onRequestSort(event, property);
  };

  return (
    <TableHead>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell padding="checkbox">
          <Checkbox
            indeterminate={numSelected > 0 && numSelected < rowCount}
            checked={numSelected === rowCount}
            onChange={onSelectAllClick}
            inputProps={{ "aria-label": "select all desserts" }}
          />
        </TableCell>
        {headCells.map(headCell => (
          <TableCell
            key={headCell.id}
            align={headCell.numeric ? "right" : "left"}
            padding={headCell.disablePadding ? "none" : "default"}
            sortDirection={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : false}
          >
            <TableSortLabel
              active={orderBy === headCell.id}
              direction={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : "asc"}
              onClick={createSortHandler(headCell.id)}
            >
              {headCell.label}
              {orderBy === headCell.id ? (
                <span className={classes.visuallyHidden}>
                  {order === "desc" ? "sorted descending" : "sorted ascending"}
                </span>
              ) : null}
            </TableSortLabel>
          </TableCell>
        ))}
      </TableRow>
    </TableHead>
  );
}

const useToolbarStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      paddingLeft: theme.spacing(2),
      paddingRight: theme.spacing(1)
    },
    highlight:
      theme.palette.type === "light"
        ? {
            color: theme.palette.secondary.main,
            backgroundColor: lighten(theme.palette.secondary.light, 0.85)
          }
        : {
            color: theme.palette.text.primary,
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.dark
          },
    title: {
      flex: "1 1 100%"
    }
  })
);

interface EnhancedTableToolbarProps {
  numSelected: number;
}

const EnhancedTableToolbar = (props: EnhancedTableToolbarProps) => {
  const classes = useToolbarStyles();
  const { numSelected } = props;

  return (
    <Toolbar
      className={clsx(classes.root, {
        [classes.highlight]: numSelected > 0
      })}
    >
      {numSelected > 0 ? (
        <Typography
          className={classes.title}
          color="inherit"
          variant="subtitle1"
        >
          {numSelected} artists selected
        </Typography>
      ) : (
        <Typography className={classes.title} variant="h6" id="tableTitle">
          Choose artists
        </Typography>
      )}
    </Toolbar>
  );
};

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      width: "100%"
    },
    paper: {
      width: "100%",
      marginBottom: theme.spacing(2)
    },
    table: {
      minWidth: 750
    },
    visuallyHidden: {
      border: 0,
      clip: "rect(0 0 0 0)",
      height: 1,
      margin: -1,
      overflow: "hidden",
      padding: 0,
      position: "absolute",
      top: 20,
      width: 1
    }
  })
);

export default (props: any) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [order, setOrder] = React.useState<Order>("asc");
  const [orderBy, setOrderBy] = React.useState<any>("name");
  //const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState<string[]>([]);
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0);
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = React.useState(5);

  const handleRequestSort = (
    event: React.MouseEvent<unknown>,
    property: any
  ) => {
    const isAsc = orderBy === property && order === "asc";
    setOrder(isAsc ? "desc" : "asc");
    setOrderBy(property);
  };

  const handleSelectAllClick = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      console.log("merker alle");
      props.values.artists.map((artist: any) => {
        artist.checked = true;
      });
      props.handleChange(props.values.artists, "artists");
    } else {
      console.log("umerker alle");
      props.values.artists.map((artist: any) => {
        artist.checked = false;
      });
      props.handleChange(props.values.artists, "artists");
    }
  };

  const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<unknown>, id: number) => {
    var prevStatus: boolean = props.values.artists.find(
      (artist: any) => artist.id === id
    ).checked;
    props.values.artists.find(
      (artist: any) => artist.id === id
    ).checked = !prevStatus;
    props.handleChange(props.values.artists, "artists");
  };

  const handleChangePage = (event: unknown, newPage: number) => {
    setPage(newPage);
    console.log("tomme sider" + emptyRows);
    console.log("rader per side" + rowsPerPage);
    console.log("sidenr " + page);
    console.log("artist " + props.values.artists);
  };

  const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (
    event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
  ) => {
    setRowsPerPage(parseInt(event.target.value, 10));
    setPage(0);
  };

  const emptyRows =
    rowsPerPage -
    Math.min(rowsPerPage, props.values.artists.length - page * rowsPerPage);

  let amtSelected = props.values.artists.filter(function(artist: any) {
    return artist.checked === true;
  }).length;

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEff");
    props.handleChange(props.values.artists, "artists");
  }, [page]);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>
        <EnhancedTableToolbar numSelected={amtSelected} />
        <TableContainer>
          <Table
            className={classes.table}
            aria-labelledby="tableTitle"
            aria-label="enhanced table"
          >
            <EnhancedTableHead
              classes={classes}
              numSelected={amtSelected}
              order={order}
              orderBy={orderBy}
              onSelectAllClick={handleSelectAllClick}
              onRequestSort={handleRequestSort}
              rowCount={props.values.artists.length}
            />
            <TableBody>
              {stableSort(props.values.artists, getSorting(order, orderBy))
                .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
                .map((row: any, index: number) => {
                  const isItemSelected = row.checked;
                  const labelId = `enhanced-table-checkbox-${index}`;

                  return (
                    <TableRow
                      hover
                      onClick={event => handleClick(event, row.id)}
                      role="checkbox"
                      aria-checked={isItemSelected}
                      tabIndex={-1}
                      key={row.name}
                      selected={isItemSelected}
                    >
                      <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                        <Checkbox
                          checked={isItemSelected}
                          inputProps={{ "aria-labelledby": labelId }}
                        />
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell
                        component="th"
                        id={labelId}
                        scope="row"
                        padding="none"
                      >
                        {row.name}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{row.email}</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  );
                })}
              {emptyRows > 0 && (
                <TableRow style={{ height: 53 * emptyRows }}>
                  <TableCell colSpan={6} />
                </TableRow>
              )}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
        <TablePagination
          rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
          component="div"
          count={props.values.artists.length}
          rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
          page={page}
          onChangePage={handleChangePage}
          onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
        />
      </Paper>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Solved! Everything got messed up because the key prop in each tablecell was not identical. Changed it from row.name to row.id, and everything worked. Really shows how important it is applying an identical key value to a component if you are mapping through an array.

Answer (score 0):

check this calculation of empty rows, you might need to adjust the height of each table row, you might be getting vertical scroll as well. Try to change colSpan and height.